# Alamofire wont work with osx in podfile instead of ios

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos, alamofire

I am trying to build a menu bar app for my macbook pro and need to make a GET request to get data from an API.  However when I try to import Alamofire I get
    `No such module 'Alamofire'`

Here is my podfile,

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :osx, '10.9'
use_frameworks!

target 'WakaMenu' do

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.3'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 3.0'

end

target 'WakaMenuTests' do

end
```

I am running Xcode 7.3 and my projects base SDK and deployment target is 10.11

When I try just using platform ios 9.0 it still shows an error as well.

Comment: Are you then doing `pod install` and opening the project.xcworkspace?

Comment: Ive done the install and ive opened the xcworkspace but Im not coding in that, im coding in the .xcodeproj file.  Is this wrong?

Comment: Yea thats the reason its not working. When you add cocoapods to a project you have to use the workspace file because xcode needs the cocoa binaries to be linked with your main project.

Comment: Opening the xcworkspace file still has the same error of `No such module Alamofire`

Comment: Try building the project though. Xcode usually reports that its not there until you build it.

Comment: Building it fails to complete.  

It has a issue "Target 'Pods-WakaMenu' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'Pods_WakaMenu.framework' because it doesn't contain platform 'macosx' in its SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS 'iphonesimulator, iphoneos'"   do I need to change the platform to macosx instead of osx?

Comment: Yep that will help

Comment: Still throws the error with the podfile edited for `platform macosx '10.9'` and the same warning.

Comment: Did you reinstall and close the project then open it again?

Comment: so i need to go into the top level directory of my project file and pod install then reopen the project?

Comment: Yes after any changes you make the the podfile you'll have to install

Comment: That fixed it after I `pod install`,  the platform needed to be osx not macosx. Once I cleaned and built it the error was gone.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :osx, '10.12'
use_frameworks!

target 'targetname' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

  pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => ‘4.3.0’
end


post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
           config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
       end
   end
end
```